# Private certificate download from aws acm after exporting to browser show Invalid certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi, aws-acm

Download private certificate from aws acm and added to nifi-application for application level ssl termination, everything is working fine but after importing the certificate in browser it is showing invalid certificate.[image: invalid certificate]

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that certificate was signed by a CA which is also not trusted by your browser. You'll need *one* of the following public certificates in your browser's truststore:
 * Edge/Node/NiFi certificate - the certificate you're viewing above
 * CA certificate - the certificate of the entity which signed this certificate ("Enterprise" according to the dialog)

Using a tool like `openssl s_client` may help with diagnosing and obtaining the certificates in the chain.

For the record, [wildcard certificates are expressly discouraged](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#wildcard_certificates) and not supported for Apache NiFi.